# highlight listview row on long press

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I have a customized listview. I want to highlight the row selected on long press. I managed to do it on normal click by using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  
  <item android:state_activated="true"   android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
  <item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
</selector>
```

but I can't figure out which state acts on long click. any ideas?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Element in Android have long click action in default . So you just need to define the **LongClick** event on the super view of adapter

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   //...
   View view = convertView;
       
   view.LongClick += View_LongClick;

   //...
       
   return view;
} 

private void View_LongClick(object sender, View.LongClickEventArgs e)
{
  var view = sender as View;
  view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
}
```